# Add element of list in dictionary of other list at the same index

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-zip

I have a list of values, and a list of dictionaries such as:

```
my_values = ["A", "B", "C"]
my_dicts = [{...}, {...}, {...}]
```

I would like to unpack my values into my dictionaries so that the value in position *n* goes in the *nth* dictionary, such as:

```
my_new_dicts = [{"value": "A", ...}, {"value": "B", ...}, {"value": "C", ...}]
```

My list/dict comprehension attempts so far yield a new list of *n*n* dictionaries.

Comment: How about `my_new_dicts = [{**d, 'value': v} for d, v in zip(my_dicts, my_values)]`

Comment: It works! Feel free to post it as an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to merge two dicts `d1` and `d2` is `{**d1, **d2}`. Instead of `**d2`, or in addition to `**d2`, you can also explicitly write the new values you want to add to `d1`.

And then using a list comprehension for `my_new_dicts`:

```py
my_new_dicts = [{**d, 'value': v} for d, v in zip(my_dicts, my_values)]
```